# Here API - what is the radius maximum

Tags: here-api

I cannot find any documentation on what the maximum radius is with the reverse geocoding endpoint. Once I go beyond something like 100 miles I seem to not see any difference in the results returned for cities around a certain location. Is there a maximum radius?

Comment: It would be helpful to check if you provide your prox parameters.

Comment: Yes I do provide the prox parameters. Example URL
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842506408691,-87.6324462890625,80467&maxresults=100&locationattributes=-mapView,-mapReference&mode=retrieveAreas&level=city&gen=9&app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX

Answer (score 0):

The API currently support maximum radius for `retrieve areas` is 50 kilometers.it depends on several factors what mode you are using and gen parameter ,contry filter etc also some more info Proximity Soft Filter
The proximity parameter is also a soft filter.

Here a single geo-coordinate pair and a radius (in
meters) is used to define the filter criterion. This may be derived from a positioning of the user's
device plus a radius.

```
While there is no hard limit for the radius, no results may be returned depending
on the input search string and Geocoder internal ranking. The smaller the radius, the more relevant
will be the results returned.
```

The recommendation is to define a radius below 250km (250000).
searchtext=paris&prox=30.6733,-82.0232,100000
The results are not ranked by distance to the position.
For example see the below request, It will give you different response if you will change the radius.

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842,-87.6388,2500&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=5&gen=9&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYYY
```

Replace your appId and appCode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is, once I go far enough out in the radius, that the maximum results is being hit? This means that we are missing results (cities). Is there anyway to get more results like pages or something?

Comment: Could you maybe review your response - the first paragraph is a bit hard to understand? Are the results affected by the maximum result limit? I believe I saw in the documentation that results are capped at 100 (seems low)